# lxml xpath syntax to access the ancestor of an XML element of specific depth?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I am trying to access ancestors of depth 3 in an XML file, i.e. for element `/a/b/c/d/e/f`, I want to get element `c`.

Here is my more realistic example input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:QDA-XML:project:1.0">
  <Sources>
    <TextSource name="document example">
      <Description />
      <PlainTextSelection>
        <Description />
        <Coding>
          <CodeRef targetGUID="a2a627dd-f7e7-4fc7-b8db-918e3ad50450" />
        </Coding>
      </PlainTextSelection>
    </TextSource>
    <VideoSource name="myvideo">
      <Transcript>
        <SyncPoint/>
        <SyncPoint/>
        <TranscriptSelection>
          <Description />
          <Coding>
            <CodeRef targetGUID="a2a627dd-f7e7-4fc7-b8db-918e3ad50450" />
          </Coding>
        </TranscriptSelection>
      </Transcript>
      <VideoSelection>
        <Coding>
          <CodeRef targetGUID="a2a627dd-f7e7-4fc7-b8db-918e3ad50450" />
        </Coding>
      </VideoSelection>
    </VideoSource>
  </Sources>
  <Notes>
    <Note name="some text">
      <Description />
      <PlainTextSelection>
        <Description />
        <Coding>
          <CodeRef targetGUID="a2a627dd-f7e7-4fc7-b8db-918e3ad50450" />
        </Coding>
      </PlainTextSelection>
    </Note>
  </Notes>
</Project>
```

In this case for instance, I want to access the elements `Note`, `TextSource` and `VideoSource` that are ancestors of `CodeRef` elements.

I have the following working code, but am wondering if there is a nicer way to go about it, perhaps using Xpath syntax:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('coderef_examples/project_simplified.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for i in root.findall('.//CodeRef', root.nsmap):
    p = tree.getelementpath(i)
    p = p.replace('{urn:QDA-XML:project:1.0}', '')
    print('namespace-free path: ', p)

    p = tree.getpath(i) # Xpath
    s = '/'.join(p.split('/')[:4]) # Xpath of depth 3
    print('xpath string: ', s)
    ancestor = root.xpath(s)[0]
    print('source tag: ', ancestor.tag, ', source name: ', ancestor.get('name'))
```

Output:

```
namespace-free path:  Sources/TextSource/PlainTextSelection/Coding/CodeRef
xpath string:  /*/*[1]/*[1]
source tag:  {urn:QDA-XML:project:1.0}TextSource , source name:  document example
namespace-free path:  Sources/VideoSource/Transcript/TranscriptSelection/Coding/CodeRef
xpath string:  /*/*[1]/*[2]
source tag:  {urn:QDA-XML:project:1.0}VideoSource , source name:  myvideo
namespace-free path:  Sources/VideoSource/VideoSelection/Coding/CodeRef
xpath string:  /*/*[1]/*[2]
source tag:  {urn:QDA-XML:project:1.0}VideoSource , source name:  myvideo
namespace-free path:  Notes/Note/PlainTextSelection/Coding/CodeRef
xpath string:  /*/*[2]/*
source tag:  {urn:QDA-XML:project:1.0}Note , source name:  some text
```

Can it be done directly in Xpath? (ideally in a way that is independent of the tag of the ancestor and the depth of the CodeRef elements)

**edit: Solution based on Conal Tuohy's answer:**

```
import lxml.etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('coderef_examples/project_simplified.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for ancestor in root.xpath('/*/*/*[descendant::qda:CodeRef]', namespaces={'qda': 'urn:QDA-XML:project:1.0'}):
    print('source tag: ', ancestor.tag, ', source name: ', ancestor.get('name'))
```

Much faster and much more efficient. It may not print an entry for every CodeRef node, but since I only want the unique ancestors, it is even better.

Comment: If you want, you can post your own Answer, but please don't add solutions to the Question.

Comment: Should I edit Conal's answer instead? (I seem to have permission to do so.)

Comment: You accepted the answer; why does it need to be edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath will return all elements which are at depth 3:

```
/*/*/*
```

(read as "any element which is the child of an element which is the child of an element which is the child of the document root")

You mention that you want elements which are ancestors of `codeRef` elements. To add that as a filter, you could do this:

```
/*/*/*[descendant::qda:codeRef]
```

(where `qda` is a namespace prefix bound to the URI `urn:QDA-XML:project:1.0`)

Comment: Thanks, that looks great! How do you specify the namespaces? I tried `root.xpath('/*/*/*[descendant::qda:codeRef]', namespaces={'qda':'urn:QDA-XML:project:1.0'})`, but it did not work.

Comment: I made a typo. Capital "C" in "CodeRef". It works! :)

Comment: Sorry, a quick follow-up question: What is the syntax to get only the ancestors where the descendant has a specific attribute? i.e. CodeRef with attribute targetGUID=xxxx?

Comment: Found it: `root.xpath('/*/*/*[descendant::qda:CodeRef/@targetGUID="a2a627dd-f7e7-4fc7-b8db-918e3ad50450"]', namespaces={'qda': 'urn:QDA-XML:project:1.0'})`

Comment: sorry `codeRef` with a lower case `c` was my mistake. Looks like you're all sorted though